# Fix my multi-table trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

This is the third in a series of questions.  Now I've got a MySQL trigger that updates a row in one table, to the new value of a row in a separate table.

Here's some visuals:

```
CREATE TABLE As (
  id
  a
) ENGINE MyISAM

CREATE TABLE Bs (
  id
  b
) ENGINE MyISAM

CREATE TABLE AbyB (
  id
  aid
  bid
)

ROWS
    | A | B  |    AbyB  |
  id| 1 | 2  |     0    |
  a | i | x  |     x    |
  b | x | i  |     x    |  -->  | x | 0 | x |
aid | x | x  |     1    |
bid | x | x  |     2    |

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1);

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER dualupdate() BEFORE INSERT INTO Bs.b
BEGIN
  SET @a = 'SELECT NEW.b';   #I don't know if I should use NEW, actually.
  SET @b = 'SELECT NEW.id';
  SET @x = 'SELECT aid FROM AbyB WHERE bid = @b';
  UPDATE As
    SET a = @a #SET is used to set variables, right?  So, am I using it wrong?
    WHERE id = @x;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a few errors, below is the correct code:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE TRIGGER ai_Bs_each AFTER INSERT ON Bs FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  UPDATE `As` 
    SET a = New.b
    WHERE id IN (SELECT aid FROM AbyB WHERE bid = NEW.id);
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's a rundown of the errors you've made:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dualupdate() BEFORE INSERT INTO Bs.b            
//This is incorrect syntax.
//This should really be an AFTER INSERT trigger. If the insert fails `As` will
//be incorrectly updated. Not unless you want to prevent the insert if the 
//update does not succeed.

BEGIN            
  SET @a = 'SELECT NEW.b';   #I don't know if I should use NEW, actually.
  //You're filling @a with a string containing the words `select` and `new`.
  //SET @a = NEW.b; will work better.
  SET @b = 'SELECT NEW.id';
  SET @x = 'SELECT aid FROM AbyB WHERE bid = @b';
  //This is a fundamental error, you can only ever put 1 result in a variable, 
  //not a resultset. 
  //If you want to use multiple values, put the select inside the update statement.
  //See my updated code.
  UPDATE As          
    SET a = @a #SET is used to set variables, right?  So, am I using it wrong?
    WHERE id = @x;      
   //This statement is (almost) correct, However `as` is a reserved word and needs
   //to be escaped in backticks ` 
END$$
```

There's no need here for the variables. You can just use the `NEW.?` directly.
Also note that MySQL does not support triggers per statement, only per row. However in future this might change so you must include `for each row`.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html
And: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

The MySQL docs are really quite good, just google `mysql statement_to_find` and the first or second result should point to the MySQL docs.

Comment: So what this basically does is updates b when a is updated, at the location where the new B.id overlaps with A.id in AbyB, right? :D

Comment: Sweet.  Thanks, Johan.  I'm going to be able to test it tonight.  I'm really excited. :)